# How to use mysqli bind_param dynamically

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a mysqli query whose where clause is generated in a for loop. So parameters are not known before runtime.

How can i use mysqli bind_param method in this case?

Can i use it in the for loop to bind parameters one by one?

Comment: Yes, but probably not in the loop that you have in mind. Can you show the code?

Comment: @neal No. You cannot

Comment: It all depends @YourCommonSense

Comment: The answer solve the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes it's possible and very simple with php5.6, first you need know how many paraments `str_repeat()`, `count()` can you help and the unpacking operator (`...`) too, so this way is possible make binds dynimic.

```
$params = [10, 50, 51, 99];
$types = str_repeat('i',count($params));

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM t WHERE id IN (?,?,?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param($types, ...$params);
if(!$stmt->excute()){
    echo mysqli_error($con);
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? is wrong? is missing something?

Comment: The code is ok.Judging by the votes in comments, there are people around who have no idea how this function works, and thus the voting

Comment: @YourCommonSense you know the unpacking arguments works fine in this case and it's ok for me, but i can put more information if is missing or delete the answer.

Comment: You can add if you wish, but the answer is ok and you should keep it.

Comment: I was looking for this to be able use bind dynamically! This does work!