# Using dynamic filter from Variable on Prepared Statements

Tags: php

I have problem with MYSQLI query prepared statements, I would like to filter out code based on post value.

Here is my code

```
    $arrfilter = array();
    if(!empty($_POST['website'])){
        $website = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['website']);
        array_push($arrfilter,"website='$website'");
    }
    if(!empty($_POST['gamename'])){
        $gamename = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['gamename']);
        array_push($arrfilter,"gamename='$gamename'");
    }
    if(!empty($_POST['action'])){
        $action = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['action']);
        array_push($arrfilter,"action='$action'");
    }
    if(count($arrfilter) > 0){
        $filter = implode(' and ',$arrfilter);
    }
    $fdate= "%$date%";
    $sql = "SELECT url,referrer,ip,user_agent,action,date FROM cpa_track WHERE date LIKE ? and ? ORDER BY date DESC";
        $process = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $process->bind_param('ss',$fdate,$filter);
        $process->execute() or die("Error: ".$conn->e

rror);
    $process->store_result();
```

My achievement is to use $filter as dynamic filter on Mysqli prepared statements. How can I do this as I received this

> Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object

Comment: `SELECT url,referrer,ip,user_agent,action,date FROM cpa_track WHERE date LIKE ? %$date% ORDER BY date DESC` is not valid sql

Comment: @bassxzero Also, not using prepared statements properly at all.

Comment: @bassxzero. I have put %$date% as bind_param anyway. I just need to fill out $filter value in the conditional.

Comment: how about this

$sql = "SELECT url,referrer,ip,user_agent,action,date FROM cpa_track WHERE date LIKE ? and ? ORDER BY date DESC";
 $process = $conn->prepare($sql);
 $process->bind_param('ss',$fdate,$filter);

I just got an empty data.

Comment: That's because your entire `$filter` string is going to be quoted when you bind it like that

Comment: @PatrickQ is there anything I can do to achieve this. My achievement is to use filter based on the post input. If it is not empty, then the filter would be included on $sql.

Comment: You could use the bind_param method like this: `$stmt->bind_param($types, ...$params);`
Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36457865/1461181

Answer (score 1):

I put this together using the code at the end of [this comment](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php#104073) on the manual page for [bind_param()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php).  I use PDO, not mysqli, so I haven't actually tested this.  The logic seems to be sound though.  The concept is that you incrementally build the parameters that will be sent to `bind_params()` and then use [reflection](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php) to apply the constructed values.  Just FYI, I find doing this far less complicated with PDO thanks to the ability to use named parameters and call `bindValue()` multiple times.

```
$conditions = "";
$types = "s";
$values = array($fdate);

if(!empty($_POST['website'])){
    $conditions .= " AND website = ?";
    $types .= "s";
    $values[] = $_POST['website'];
}
if(!empty($_POST['gamename'])){
    $conditions .= " AND gamename = ?";
    $types .= "s";
    $values[] = $_POST['gamename'];
}
if(!empty($_POST['action'])){
    $conditions .= " AND action = ?";
    $types .= "s";
    $values[] = $_POST['action'];
}

$bindArray = array($types);

foreach($values as $value)
{
    $bindArray[] = $value;
}

$fdate= "%$date%";
$sql = "SELECT url,referrer,ip,user_agent,action,date FROM cpa_track WHERE date LIKE ? $conditions ORDER BY date DESC";
$process = $conn->prepare($sql);

$refClass = new ReflectionClass('mysqli_stmt'); 
$refMethod = $refClass->getMethod("bind_param");
$refMethod->invokeArgs($process,$bindArray);

$process->execute() or die("Error: ".$conn->error);
$process->store_result();
```

Comment: Do I have to use `mysqli_real_escape_string` if I bind parameters?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2284327/1461181

Comment: @DanielO. No.  I was just copying what OP had.  I wouldn't do both.  I _would_ suggest maybe doing some sort of requirements-based sanitization/validation of the inputs, but from a technical standpoint, the binding is all you need.

Comment: @mickmackusa What specifically would you like to see? Considering this only has 1 upvote, wasn't accepted as an answer, and is 3+ years old, I can't imagine there's a whole lot of people clamoring to use this as a dupe target.

Comment: @mickmackusa  I removed the calls to `mysqli_real_escape_string()`